# How to break promise chain nested into another promise chain

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise

I am unable to figure out how to break a nested promise chain into a main promise chain. Here is my code :

```
 //Main Promise chain
 let promiseMain = Promise.resolve(1)
        .then(result => functionA())
        .then(result => nestedChain()).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(result => functionC())

//chain error handler
function chainError(err) {
return Promise.reject(err)
};

function nestedChain()
{
stepOne()
.then(stepTwo, chainError)
.then(stepThreee, chainError)
.catch((error) => 
    {
        console.log(error);
        return undefined;
    });          
}

function stepOne() 
{
    return chainError("error attempt : 1.00");
}
```

Once I go into the nestedChain where I throw an error in stepOne() I am able to break this nestedChain. Awesome!

The problem: It also breaks the main promise chain. So.. when it goes into nestedChain() and the error is thrown from stepOne(), functionC from the main promise chain will never be executed because the rejected promise from the nestedChain also break this chain.

Comment: `Promise`s won't throw - you're thinking of the behavior exhibited by `async`/`await`

Comment: That explain my failure with the try/catch thanks! But still.. is it possible to break only in the nested chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to attach with promises chain, do something like this

```
function nestedChain()
{ 
  stepOne()
  .then(stepTwo, chainError)
  .then(stepThreee, chainError)
  .catch ((error) => {
               console.log(error);
               return undefined;
            })
}
```

Comment: I tried this by throwing an error in stepOne() and I get an unhandle rejection and everything breaks also the main chain.

Comment: Post your complete code, error must be throwing somewhere else, attach error logs if possible

Answer (score 1):

Promise are implemented to wait for something which take more time. You just need to implement promise correctly.

For example if we have 3 function returning promise and one nested function also returning promise, this is how it's implemented:

```
functionA()
.then( result => {
    return functionB();
})
.then( result => {
    return nestedFunct();
})
.then( result => {
    return functionC();
})
.then( result => {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch( error => {
    console.log(`Error in one of the above function`);
});
```

All the function are of format similar too

```
function functionA() {
    return new Promise( (resilve, reject) => {
        resolve('something');
        // or
        reject('Error');
    });
}
```

Nested function can be like this

```
function nestedFunc() {
    return functionD()          // Return promise
    .then( result => {
        return functionE();     // return promise
    })
    .then( result => {
        return functionF();      // return promise or value
    });
}
```

Main promise chain is not affected by what individual function do as long as they keep returning promise. All individual function can have a local promise chain. Even if an error occurred in nested chain will be catched by `catch()` in main promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correct, you need to catch error after nested chain promise

```
Promise.resolve().then(()=> {
  console.log('A');
}).then(() => {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log('step 1');
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('step 2');
    throw new Error('Step 2 error');
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
}).then(() => {
  console.log('C');
});
```

Comment: If I catch the error, the code still going and it won't break the nestedchain. 
Also, if I catch the error thrown from the nestedchain into the mainchain, the mainChain doesn't catch anything.

Comment: Parent chain can catch error from nested chain's throwing error. What did you really want to do. I confused about your comment what you say :)